# Solids to liquids process

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-state-theory

Melting point is the critical point at which a solid starts to be transformed into a liquid? Does this mean that the geometric lattice of a solid is broken?

Comment: The notion is right, but you have to be careful. Glass does not have a matrix, but it still melts.

Comment: I mean for solids that do have a lattice.

Comment: I don't understand what [tag:transition-state-theory] tag has to do with melting of crystalline matter. Why have you decided to add this tag? Also, could you please elaborate a bit more on what exactly what exactly you are interested in? Currently the question seems trivial to me, but I suspect you are trying to ask something else.